# Package 'samba' is virtual - Error when installing Samba

Tags: 12.10, samba, file-sharing

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu computer as a centralised storage for a few Windows 7 computers on my network. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10.

However, when I try to install Samba through the terminal using `sudo apt-get install samba`, I get this error:

```
Package samba is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

If I try to install it by clicking on the directory I want to share, then checking "Share this folder" to trigger the "Sharing service is not installed, Install Server" dialogue box, it results in these errors:

```
Package 'samba' is virtual.
Package 'libpam-smbpass' is virtual.
Sharing service installation failed
```

I can't seem to find any information online about these errors - can someone help?

Comment: Did you `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I resolved this by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm surprised the system doesn't automatically do an "apt-get update" immediately after installation  - but the above fixes this.

Comment: Looks like this was the problem - I remember getting an "Update Failed" type message on installation. The issue is fixed now - thanks!